# Returning the text (string value) of an enum value

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum Lang
{
    English = 0,
    Romaji = 1,
    Kana = 2,
    Kanji = 3,
}
```

I know I can write:

```
var a = Lang.English
var b = a;
```

and set `b` to be equal to 0. However is there any way that I can set `b` equal to `"English"` if given `a`?

Comment: Please clarify. To my understanding, the above statements would already set `b` to `Lang.English`, which would correspond to an integer value of `0`.

Comment: Do you mean `b.ToString()` ?

Comment: `var b = a.ToString()`

Comment: Basically, assume printing `a` would print "English", he wants `b` to do the same instead of printing `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially an `enum` is a set of named constants. So instead of using the constants, you use their names to make your code more readable.

The value of `b` would be equal to the named constant `Lang.English` and it's type wouldn't be of a `string` but it would be of `Lang`. So casting `b` to an `int`, you would get 0.

> However is there any way that I can set b equal to "English" if given
>   a?

Yes, you could try the following:

```
string b = Enum.GetName(typeof(Lang),Lang.English);
```

For a demo, please have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9j779V)